# varnish don't resolve ESI in my localhost

Tags: apache, http-headers, gzip, varnish

varnish don't resolve ESI in my localhost:

i have similar configuration like other users in apache, but i send/get following headers:

```
Server  Apache/2.2.21 (Debian)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.8-2
Content-Encoding    gzip
Edge-Control    cache-maxage=31536000s
Cache-Control   public, max-age=31536000
Pragma  public
Expires Tue, 30 Oct 2012 11:41:15 GMT
ProcessID   3918
Etag    c2e6665981c6441ab860d12a6853a002
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length  4193
Date    Mon, 31 Oct 2011 10:40:54 GMT
X-Varnish   630755530
Age 0
Via 1.1 varnish
Request Headersview source
Host    i.host.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1 Iceweasel/7.0.1
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  OAX=1I6M006JYzwABwNj; __utma=164510763.315921951.1317626740.1319722611.1319795071.39; __utmz=164510763.1317626740.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=229641156.678788339.1317628577.1320057939.1320060143.19; __utmz=229641156.1317628577.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); lang=es; __utmc=229641156; __utmb=229641156.4.10.1320060143
If-None-Match   c2e6665981c6441ab860d12a6853a002
Cache-Control   max-age=0
```

other user example that works:

```
Server  Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) PHP/5.3.5
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.5
Set-Cookie  lang=es; expires=Mon, 31-Oct-2011 11:46:01 GMT; path=/
Edge-control    cache-maxage=31536000s
Cache-Control   public, max-age=31536000
Pragma  public
Expires Tue, 30 Oct 2012 10:46:01 GMT
ProcessID   3824
Etag    f9dcd4b1ec3f40e6763e80a3ba195de3
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Date    Mon, 31 Oct 2011 10:46:01 GMT
X-Varnish   630755925
Age 0
Via 1.1 varnish
Connection  keep-alive
Cabeceras de la peticiónver fuente
Host    t.host.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  OAX=1I6M001BiwUAB0EE; __utma=164510763.1374034467.1296142874.1319189845.1319204625.107; __utmz=164510763.1319204625.107.79.utmcsr=tamara.eitb.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/eu/eguraldia/eskia/; __utma=261580168.2132154740.1302611206.1319197586.1320057948.90; __utmz=261580168.1302611206.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); lang=es; __utmb=261580168.1.10.1320057948; __utmc=261580168
```

i don't know why i receive different headers from varnish...

i get:

```
Content-Encoding    gzip
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

why i get this headers and the other users no???

both have mod_deflate on...

Answer (score 0):

you´re getting both Content-Encoding and Vary in order to Varnish, an a user-agent, properly handle the request. While Content-Encoding tells Vanish, an a user-agent, that the page content is encoded in a zip format, gzip in your case, the header Vary tells, specially Varnish to cache both versions of the page with or without gzip compression.
If backend is compression encoding aware, it can deliver a version with compression (gzip or deflate) or it can deliver a version withou any compression (text/html for example).

But, to enable ESI processing in varnish, use the esi; command on your vcl file. See this [page](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ESIfeatures) for more information:

Comment: i'm developer i can't access to varnish server :( sysadmin don't help me, says to fix it by client side (my side) but i don't know why i get this headers and the other win users no :(